# PHP - Most efficient way to compare if one SQL timestamp is earlier than another

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

If I have two SQL timestamp strings:

```
$t1 = '2014-06-20 00:00:00';
$t2 = '2013-02-17 00:00:00';
```

What is the most efficient way to establish if one is earlier than the other?

**Edit:** I know many ways to do this. I'm asking what is the quickest and most efficient way. I was wondering if there are methods I am unaware of.

Comment: It's in the manual http://www.php.net//manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: In a SQL query it would be `<` or `>`

Comment: These are [datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) strings

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know. Is that the most efficient way though? Doesn't seem it to me, instantiating classes and such.

Comment: *"Edit: I know many ways to do this. I'm asking what is the quickest and most efficient way."* --- That depends on what your application needs are. If you're querying a DB with thousands of records, there are many possible factors at play. Ask one of the guys below about the answers they've given to elaborate on their methods used. Whatever's listed in the manual is but the basics. Then comes loops, queries etc. too many things at play. However, a ternary operator works rather nicely as John demonstrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good thing about the above format is that alphabetical sorting is the same as date sorting. This means you can do:

```
$t1 < $t2
```

Of course if it's possible for the format to change then this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime()` objects are comparable.

```
$t1 = new DateTime('2014-06-20 00:00:00');
$t2 = new DateTime('2013-02-17 00:00:00');
echo ($t1 < $t2) ?
    't1 is earlier than t2' :
    't2 is earlier than t1';
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/l8agYs)

Comment: Plus a demo, plus a ternary operator. You're really going to town ;-)

Comment: I'm wearing my fancy pants today. :)

Comment: @JohnConde Is this slower than Jim's method?

Comment: There is no slow here. Technically minie is slower but it's so fast you and your users will *never* notice. What is different is mine works with any valid date format. If you are absolutely sure your dates will always be in YYYY-MM-DD format, use Jim's method. Otherwise, use mine.

Comment: @JohnConde. 100% sure in this particular scenario. Thanks.